# Android JUnit Test for Class

Tags: android, junit

I am such a beginner in Android and I don't have any experience with JUnit. I am wondering if it is possible to directly use android api (ex. Camera.getNumberOfCameras()) inside the JUnit class. Actually, I have tried doing that although it compiled successfully, when I execute the test case I am getting ClassNotDefined error. Maybe I am missing something here.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
artsylar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/testing/testing_eclipse.html#CreateTestProjectEclipse